# Regex search a table of strings to check if they are in another table of notes

Tags: sql, regex

I have a data table (we will call this Table1) in SQL Developer that is a list of VARCHAR stings (in this case a list of medications) and another data table (we will call it Table2) that has a list of Notes from a doctors office. I am wondering if there is a way to use regular expressions to identify if a note has mentions any of the medications from table1 and also show that medication as a 1/0 indicator.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things with regex, simple text search is likely enough.

Comment: Lets say you have 1000 medications. And 500,000 notes. That's 500 million independent string comparisons to find all meds that are within each note. If you create a full blown ternary trie of the meds that drops down to 500,000 searches, a full 1000 x less time. It scales too.